# Error for expo-cli when installing with Node 18

Tags: node.js, react-native, expo

[image]

I am trying to install expo-cli and there appears to be an error related to the node version. Is there a way to install it without installing Node 16?

I have even tried using `npx expo init my-project` but it doesn't see to work, it landed on an error of `Invalid project root: /Users/...`

Comment: There might not be a fix; Node 18, at the current state, is an unstable version, and that is most likely why `expo-cli` doesn't support it. Right now, your best bet is to downgrade to Node 16, and upgrade to Node 18 when it becomes LTS.